# hashcode hashmap and equals

Tags: hashmap, hashcode

Where am I getting wrong is following understanding?

**Scenario 1:**

```
Float[] f1= new Float[2];
Float[] f2= new Float[2];
System.out.println("Values"+f1[0]+","+f2[0]+","+(f1==f2));
```

Output:  0.0, 0.0, false.

What I understood from this is:

1) Whenever we declare a float type array all the values are initialized to 0.0

2) Though both f1 and f2 have same values, they are pointing to different addressed in Heap.

3) .equals() in Object Class compares address of the values in head along with the values.

```
    HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap();
    String str1 = new String("test");
    String str2 = new String("test");
    System.out.println((str1==str2));
    System.out.println((str1.hashCode()==str2.hashCode()));

    hashMap.put(str1,1);
    hashMap.put(str2,2);
    System.out.println(hashMap.get(str1));
```

Output:false
true
2

**Scenario 2**

What I understood from this is
1) Two immutable string literals "test" are created. Both of them are pointing to different locations in the memory

2) From Oracle Docs, if values returned by equals is same then the value returned hashcode must be same and not vice versa. So deflection from equals method in second output is justifiable (i.e. in comparison of hashValue).  **How is hashCode internally working in this case? Isn't it comparing address? Here they are pointing to different locations so they should have different addresses right?**

3) They have same hashCode so hashMap is replacing the value of str1 with str2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scenario #1
1) Whenever we declare a float type array all the values are initialized to 0.0
Yes that true

2) Though both f1 and f2 have same values, they are pointing to different addressed in Heap.
Yes you are comparing the refrence of two arrays with in the heap.

3) .equals() in Object Class compares address of the values in head along with the values.
yes its same as Answer for #2 above. It compares reference of two objects.

Scenario #2
1) Two immutable string literals "test" are created. Both of them are pointing to different locations in the memory
Yes that's true.

2) From Oracle Docs, if values returned by equals is same then the value returned hashcode must be same and not vice versa. So deflection from equals method in second output is justifiable (i.e. in comparison of hashValue). How is hashCode internally working in this case? Isn't it comparing address? Here they are pointing to different locations so they should have different addresses right?

This is how hashCode method works on String:

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
        char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            h = 31 * h + val[i];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

3) They have same hashCode so hashMap is replacing the value of str1 with str2.
In addition to hashCode, it would check for equality of two objects as well and if both condition satisfies then it will overwrite the value for the key which is same.

Comment: In addition to hashCode, it would check for equality of two objects as well and if both condition satisfies then it will overwrite the value for the key which is same.

-- If I am understanding it correctly, you meant that it will compare the actual value (i.e. without respect to address but with respect to actual value contained in it.). Am I correct?

Comment: Yes so if you overrided equals method in your key object then it will compare based on that else it will compare two refrences.